# Detect the OpenGL context profile before version 3.2

Tags: c++, opengl, compatibility, profile

I'm trying to detect a profile of a default OpenGL context created using [glfw](https://www.glfw.org/). This is the way I've implemented it (based on the [wiki page](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context))

```
std::string openGLProfile(){
   // Prints the profile of the current context

   GLint profile = 0;
   glGetIntegerv(GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, &profile);

   bool core_profile = profile & GL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT;
   bool compatibility_profile = profile & GL_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT;

   std::string str = "No profile";

   if (core_profile == true)
       str = "Core profile";

   else if (compatibility_profile == true)
       str = "Compatibility";

   std::cout << str;
}
```

The problem is that this enumerator `GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK` is apparently not available in some OpenGL versions, like 2.1 and this causes an error.

My question is - how to do the profile check for OpenGL versions that do not have the GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK? Also, if somebody could point me to the documentation where this profile mask was first introduced, I'd find it very useful. Apparently, the [doc for OpenGL 4.xx about glGetIntegerv](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGet.xhtml) does not even mention the profile mask, which confuses me.

Comment: "*how to do the profile check for OpenGL versions that do not have the GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK?*" If they don't have that... they don't have *profiles*. So it's a non-question.

Comment: Re. `"how to do the profile check for OpenGL versions that do not have the GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK?"`: you don't.  Profiles didn't exist until OpenGL version 3.2 (I think?).  So you need to check the version of OpenGL associated with the current context before deciding on whether or not to check the profile type.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I know it when I run the code and get the error. I don't want to get the error to know it.
The point was that before 3.2 there were no profiles, so checking the right version limit was what I needed.

Comment: @MarsaPalas: My point is that before you can even *ask* for the profile mask, you *have to* know that you're dealing with 3.2+. Either because you requested such a context or because you checked the version number before asking for the profile mask.

Comment: @MarsaPalas: Answers should be placed in the "Add Answer" section; you shouldn't edit questions to put the answer text in them. It's OK to answer your own question.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks, I didn't know that. On the other hand, I think The Dreams Wind has provided the best implementation because it also checks extensions, so I think that should be marked as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to do the profile check for OpenGL versions that do not have the GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK?

To be precise, OpenGL didn't have notion of profiles until version 3.2, because the most versions before (up to 2.1) were backward compatible. That became a problem when OpenGL 3.0 introduced deprecated functionality and OpenGL 3.1 just removed some functionality from specification. Different vendors, however, kept supporting the backward compatibility via extensions and you had different versions of OpenGL specification existing at the same time. In order to differentiate between them the profiles were introduced, but only in version 3.2.

The most correct answer to your question, is that profiles didn't exist before OpenGL 3.2 and technically there is no profile. However if we boil down this question to how to express profiles dichotomy in older OpenGL versions, then the answer would be as follows:

- **OpenGL up to 2.1** - supports compatibility profile only (all contexts were backwards compatible)
- **OpenGL 3.0** - despite deprecating many legacy features, they still worked for 3.0, so *predominantly* 3.0 is compatibility profile, with one exception - if it has `GL_CONTEXT_FLAG_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT`, it means 3.0 simulates 3.1 experience, where the backward compatibility is removed and thus it's core profile.
- **OpenGL 3.1** - as [the documentation says](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) for this version if `GL_ARB_compatibility` is present among extensions string, then all deprecated functions are supported, so it can be treated as compatibility (and core otherwise)
- **OpenGL 3.2 and newer** - gives this information with use of `GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK`

Actual code would look like this (sorry for the verbose OpenGL version utility functions, but they come handy here)

```cpp
constexpr GLint GLV(GLint major, GLint minor) {
    constexpr auto majorShift = std::numeric_limits<GLint>::digits / 2 - 1;
    return (major << majorShift) | minor;
}

GLint glVersion() {
    constexpr auto invalid_version = -1;
    const auto glVersionString{ reinterpret_cast<const char*>(glGetString(GL_VERSION)) };
    
    GLint major;
    const auto majorResult = std::from_chars(glVersionString, glVersionString + 1, major).ec;
    if (majorResult == std::errc::invalid_argument) {
        return invalid_version;
    }
    
    GLint minor;
    const auto minorResult = std::from_chars(glVersionString + 2, glVersionString + 3, minor).ec;
    if (minorResult == std::errc::invalid_argument) {
        return invalid_version;
    }
    
    return GLV(major, minor);
}

void reportGLProfile() {  
    const auto glV = glVersion();
    if (glV <= GLV(2, 1)) {
        std::cout << "Compatibility profile" << std::endl;
    } else if (glV == GLV(3, 0)) {
        GLint flags;
        glGetIntegerv(GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, &flags);
        if (flags & GL_CONTEXT_FLAG_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT) {
            std::cout << "Core profile" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Compatibility profile" << std::endl;
        }
    } else if (glV == GLV(3, 1)) {
        GLint extensionsNum;
        glGetIntegerv(GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS, &extensionsNum);
        while (extensionsNum--) {
            const auto extensionName = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(glGetStringi(GL_EXTENSIONS, extensionsNum));
            if (std::strcmp(extensionName, "GL_ARB_compatibility") == 0) {
                std::cout << "Compatibility profile" << std::endl;
                return;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Core profile" << std::endl;
    } else {
        GLint profile;
        glGetIntegerv(GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, &profile);
        
        if (const auto errorCode = glGetError()) {
            std::cout << "Pending GL error while obtaining profile: " << errorCode << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        
        if (profile & GL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT) {
            std::cout << "Core profile" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Compatibility profile" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

---

> if somebody could point me to the documentation where this profile mask was first introduced, I'd find it very useful

That is covered by [Context Types](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Context_types) documentation:

> The 3.0 form of context creation did not have the concept of profiles. There was only one form of OpenGL: the core specification. In 3.2, OpenGL was effectively split into two profiles, core and compatibility. An implementation was only required to define core, so compatibility is not guaranteed to be available

Comment: _"Just assume it has only core profile for OpenGL earlier than 3.2"_ — This doesn't make sense: GL 2.1 is more like compatibility profile, since it has all the deprecated API. Then, a GL 3.0 context might be a forward-compatible one, so it'd be indeed closer to the core profile (not sure if this can be queried whether it's forward-compatible). But in 3.1, if `GL_ARB_compatibility` extension is available, it's once again closer to a compatibility profile.

Comment: @Ruslan I agree. Up until 3.0 things were backward compatible. Starting 3.1, functionalities marked as deprecated in 3.0 were removed and could only be reached through GL_ARB_compatibility extension.

The Dreams Wind, so the gist is that checking the version first would do the trick. I've tested the code you've written, and got 'Invalid enumerant' again, because apparently glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &major); and glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &minor); is causing it. Instead I've ended up using glGetString(GL_VERSION) and that worked.

Comment: @Ruslan fair enough, i'll adjust this part

Comment: I think there's a slight mistake in reportGLProfile, because the check has to include 2.1, so if (glV <= GLV(2, 1)).
Other than that, I think it's a very good answer, I'll mark it as the final one.

Comment: @MarsaPalas good catch, fixed